# element wise multiply sub-array and array fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran90

I want to element wise multiply two arrays A and a sub array of B in fortran(90)

A is 4d and B is 5d. Initially I tried this but the compiler doesn't like it

```
C(:,:,:,:)=A(:,:,:,:)*B(:,:,:,:,1)
```

is there an easy way to extract B(:,:,:,:,1) as a 4d array such that I can do the binary operation *?

*edit - error message from compiler*

```
tracer1_field(:,:,:,:) = tbase(:,:,:,:,1)*domain(:,:,:,:) ! *12*12*!2 due to grid size.
                              1
Error: Rank mismatch in array reference at (1) (5/4)
```

Comment: How did the compiler complain? What was the error message if any? What idiom of Fortran are you using and what compiler and/or compiler options were used?

Comment: @PierredeBuyl i'll add the error message to the original post. I'm compiling with gfortran at the moment although I may move over to the cray compiler at a later stage. I'm writing it in f90 as that's what the original codebase for the model was written in but I'm relatively new to Fortran so not sure of the differences between idioms

Comment: Can you add to the post the declaration lines of the arrays? The error seems to be that `tbase` is of rank 4 instead of anything else. I'd check that before anything.

Comment: @PierredeBuyl you're right on checking I'd been putting tbase into the wrong allocation function, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error refers to the rank of the array `tbase` that is declared with four indices and not five.